# Merging three Active Record arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activerecord

I'm trying to merge three Active Record arrays in a Rails 5 app so that I have a nice collection of jobs, forum threads and blogs on my home page.

I have the following code:

`application_controller.rb`

```
def home
  @blogs = Blog.limit(6)
  @jobs = Job.where(approved: true).limit(6)
  @forum_threads = ForumThread.includes(:forum_posts).limit(6)
  @everything = @blogs + @jobs + @forum_threads
end
```

`home.html.erb`

```
<% @everything.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse.each do |item| %>
    <% if item.is_a?(Job) %>
      <%= render partial: "application/partials/home_job", locals: {item: item} %>
    <% elsif item.is_a?(ForumThread) %>
      <%= render partial: "application/partials/home_forum", locals: {item: item} %>
    <% elsif item.is_a?(Blog) %>
      <%= render partial: "application/partials/home_blog", locals: {item: item} %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem I'm having is that this code doesn't display the records in date order by `created_by`, instead I have a rather random collection of jobs, forum threads and blogs starting at a seemingly random date.

If I add, say, a new job, it doesn't appear in the collection displayed on `/home` page. However, if I delete all records from the db and start adding new records then the code works fine and displays the posts in the correct order with the behaviour I expect.

I can't push this code live to Heroku because I can't delete all the records that already exist in production. It's almost like there's some kind of cache that needs clearing out. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @blogs = Blog.order(created_at: :desc).limit(6)
```

etc.

Comment: Good in principle.  I''d suggest `Blog.order(created_at: :desc).limit(6)` otherwise the limit is provided before the order and latest may not be included.

Comment: If I do this then the three different collections get grouped together. So all the blog posts sit next to each other, the jobs next to each other... I want them all intermingled and sorted by created_by

Comment: No, you can still do the @everything and then the `sort_by`... @KcUS_unico answer just ensures you get the right records first.

Comment: Needs to be `(created_at: :desc)` or `('created_at desc')` otherwise you only get oldest records.

Comment: @ SteveTurczyn => Thanks

Comment: @SteveTurczyn yeah I took out the `sort_by` but keeping it in and it works. Thanks both of you @KcUS_unico

Comment: Hi, made a small tweak to the answer... if using hash format `field: :asc` you don't use quotes.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1: Getting the right records from the database**

**Option A**: If you will always be sorting each model by the created_at value (a common desire), add a default_scope to each model (Rails 4+ version below). Your limit calls in the controller will automatically take advantage of the default scope.

`app/models/blog.rb`

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order created_at: :desc }
  ...
end
```

**Option B**: If you only do this in certain circumstances, but you do it for several models, I like to extract that into a Timestamped module (below). You will need to use the most_recent method in your controller when extracting records from the database to ensure you're getting the most recent ones.

`app/models/concerns/timestamped.rb`

```
module Timestamped
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :most_recent,  -> { order created_at: :desc }
    scope :least_recent, -> { order created_at: :asc }
    scope :most_fresh,   -> { order updated_at: :desc }
    scope :least_fresh,  -> { order updated_at: :asc }
  end
end

class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Timestamped
  ...
end
```

**Problem 2: Sorting the array**

Even with a simple case like this, I'd recommend adding an array extension that matches the most_recent method that timestamped.rb defines for ActiveRecord::Relations.

`lib/array_extensions.rb`

```
class Array
  def most_recent
    sort { |a, b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at }
  end
end
```

and then require the extension with an initializer:

`config/initializers/extensions.rb`

```
require 'array_extensions'
```

**Problem 3: Keeping the controller clean.**

Generally each controller action should only set up one instance variable, and in this case it looks like you are not even using the @blogs, @jobs, and @forum_threads variables in the views. Vivek's answer solves this, although I'd do the flattening and sorting logic in the controller:

```
def home
  @posts = Blog.most_recent.limit(6) + Job.approved.most_recent.limit(6) + ForumThread.most_recent.includes(:forum_posts).limit(6)
  @posts = @posts.most_recent
end
```

**Problem 4: Minimize if/then logic in your view**

Instead of this:

```
<% @everything.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse.each do |item| %>
  <% if item.is_a?(Job) %>
    <%= render partial: "application/partials/home_job", locals: {item: item} %>
  <% elsif item.is_a?(ForumThread) %>
    <%= render partial: "application/partials/home_forum", locals: {item: item} %>
  <% elsif item.is_a?(Blog) %>
    <%= render partial: "application/partials/home_blog", locals: {item: item} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Do this:

```
<% @everything.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse.each do |item| %>
  <%= render "application/partials/home_#{item.class.name.underscore}", item: item %>
<% end %>
```

And make sure your partials are named appropriately

Comment: Thanks for this. For now I'm going with Option A, but I just refactored my code to clean the controller and to avoid the if/else statements in the view. I didn't even know you could do `"application/partials/home_#{item.class.name.underscore}"` so thanks for teaching me something new

Comment: glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
def home
  @collections=[]
  @collections << Blog.limit(6)
  @collections << Job.where(approved: true).limit(6)
  @collections << ForumThread.includes(:forum_posts).limit(6)
end

<% @collections.flatten.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse.each do |item| %>

....iteration here ....

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question correctly, you want to sort the array after you merged it by date. I would do it like that:

```
@everything = @everything.sort {|x| x.created_at }
```

Hope that helps.